# Problemas con Group_by Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Sucede que uso un **group_by** para dividir los post segun su año por medio de un scope, y funciona fenomenal me imprime los post en grupos por año, el problema es que al migrar a Rails5, siempre me los divide pero me imprime los demas post aunque no correspondan a ese año, si tengo un post de 2014, me imprime todos, de ahi el siguiente grupo un post del 2015, me imprime debajo de el todos los demas, no se exactamente que estara pasando, dejo mi codigo, para sugerencias y ayuda, saludos!

**Index.html.erb**

```
<% @enterprises.group_by { |a| a.created_at.year }.each do |year, enterprises| %>
      <h5><b><%= year %></b></h5>
    <% @enterprises.each do |enterprise| %>
        <div class="main-section">
          <h5><b><%= enterprise.name %></b></h5>
          <p><%= enterprise.enterprise_tag.name %></p>
          <p><%= truncate(enterprise.about, length: 140) %></p>
        </div>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
```

**enterprise.rb**

```
class Enterprise < ApplicationRecord
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  def self.year
     where(created_at: Time.zone.now.beginning_of_year..Time.zone.now.end_of_year)
  end

end
```

Comment: Hola Hector, en lugar de editar la pregunta para indicar que encontraste la respuesta, escribe una respuesta. En Stack Overflow es algo que está permitido y se fomenta. Por favor, copia esa última edición a una respuesta. Para más información sobre el tema, lee [answer] y [¿Puedo responder a mi propia pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Lo solucione amigo, luego de darle vuelta al asunto, me preguntaba porque realizaba una doble impresión de datos, hasta que me di cuenta que en el segundo each no llamaba a la variable "enterprise" sino que lo llamaba de nuevo de esta forma "@enterprise", es decir que lo correcto quedari asi:

```
<% @enterprises.group_by { |a| a.created_at.year }.each do |year, enterprises| %>
      <h5><b><%= year %></b></h5>
      <% enterprises.each do |enterprise| %>
       <!-- contenido -->
      <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Saludos, dejare la publicacion para futuras referencias